# Library Sources are not available in SuperDevMode

Tags: java, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse, gwt-super-dev-mode

I created a demo project [here](https://github.com/confile/Realtime-JSON-Test).

It compile with GWT compile without any problems from Eclipse. When I run the app in SuperDevMode the first compile failed with the following errors:

```
        Compiling 1 permutation
            Compiling permutation 0...
            [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:121)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:140)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.Devirtualizer.getStaticImpl(Devirtualizer.java:562)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.Devirtualizer.access$400(Devirtualizer.java:75)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.Devirtualizer$RewriteVirtualDispatches.ensureDevirtualVersionExists(Devirtualizer.java:184)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.Devirtualizer$RewriteVirtualDispatches.endVisit(Devirtualizer.java:101)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:580)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:183)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:355)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JInterfaceType.traverse(JInterfaceType.java:75)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:380)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JProgram.visitModuleTypes(JProgram.java:1192)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JProgram.traverse(JProgram.java:1156)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:380)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.Devirtualizer.execImpl(Devirtualizer.java:320)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.Devirtualizer.exec(Devirtualizer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler$MonolithicPermutationCompiler.normalizeSemantics(MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$PermutationCompiler.compilePermutation(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:290)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.compilePermutation(MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.UnifiedAst.compilePermutation(UnifiedAst.java:143)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilePerms.compile(CompilePerms.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory$ThreadedPermutationWorker.compile(ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.PermutationWorkerFactory$Manager$WorkerThread.run(PermutationWorkerFactory.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
    ... 27 more
               [ERROR] <no source info>: <source info not available>
               [ERROR] at JsonElement.java(19): public abstract JsonElement clear();

                  com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
               [ERROR] at JsonElement.java(18): interface JsonElement extends Serializable 
                  com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JInterfaceType
               [ERROR] at Unknown(0): <JProgram>
                  com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JProgram
            [ERROR] Unrecoverable exception, shutting down
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationProblemReporter.logAndTranslateException(CompilationProblemReporter.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$PermutationCompiler.compilePermutation(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:367)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.compilePermutation(MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.UnifiedAst.compilePermutation(UnifiedAst.java:143)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilePerms.compile(CompilePerms.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory$ThreadedPermutationWorker.compile(ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.PermutationWorkerFactory$Manager$WorkerThread.run(PermutationWorkerFactory.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            [ERROR] Not all permutation were compiled , completed (0/1)
      [WARN] recompile failed
      [WARN] continuing to serve previous version
```

The library uses the `<super-source path="super" />` tag. From the GWT documentation I found (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html)

" In development mode, the native JRE classes always supercede classes compiled from source."

This is a problem because I cannot use the lib in SuperDevMode.

**Is there any way to fix this? Can I omit the super-source tag in some way?**

Answer (score 1):

You are using java code not prepared for GWT, it seems the problem is `JsonElement` which probably comes from `com.google.gson` which is a library not compatible with GWT.

You might read the GWT coding [compatibilty](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html) and [jre](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) emulation documentation.

Comment: If I Compiler with gwt it Workshop but mit in Super Dev Mode.

Comment: Sounds like a problem in your classpath, and different version of module files or java classes, so in SDM some client class is using the JsonElement.

Answer (score 1):

In case it might help, I experienced a similar issue, due to a `static` field in an anonymous class (`String` in my case); although this is accepted in both standard and GWT-emulation JDK, it seems to cause the above-mentioned `com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException` at SuperDevMode startup (I am using GWT 2.7.0). Just moving the offending field out of the anonymous class was enough to get rid of the exception.